# Is it possible to common reserved words/functions in clojure

Tags: clojure, metaprogramming

Disclaimer: I have very little experience with clojure and I'm want to know whether it is possible before I invest time into learning the language

I'm looking for a language that allows the programmer to redefine common reserved words/symbols such as "if", "and", "class", "=" etc so that I can create a DSL for generating code in other languages

For example:

```
(class "SomeClassName"
    (private (static ("someProperty" (= (array
         '("SomeKey" "SomeValue")))))
```

would return some data structure that could be translated to the following php

```
class SomeClassName {
    private static $someProperty = array("SomeKey" => "SomeValue");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few real reserved words/functions in clojure, almost all of them are simply functions or macros (such as [and](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L807), [=](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L748) and [let](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4301)).

The special functions/words that are truly reserved are called "special forms" and you can read about them [here](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms) (like `if`, `do`, etc..)